# Set JAVA_HOME and MAVEN_HOME using .bat file

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, java-home

I created a .bat file that set the maven home and the java home :

```
@echo off
@setlocal

SETX /M JAVA_HOME $."/Java/jdk1.8.0_181"
echo %JAVA_HOME%
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%

SET MAVEN_HOME=$."/apache-maven-3.6.3"
echo %MAVEN_HOME%
set PATH=%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;%PATH%

java -jar .\RestCallAutomation.jar
```

but it always shows me this ERROR:

```
RÉUSSITE : la valeur spécifiée a été enregistrée.
"/Java/jdk1.8.0_181"
"/apache-maven-3.6.3"
'java' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the full path to the java and maven directories?

Comment: @JakobF no I need the reduced path because I 'm creating a bat file to run this app on what ever desktop !(i.e: I have a folder which contain java & maven so I need to set the maven and java Home to those files using .bat file)

Comment: If the folders are always in the same location relative to the bat file you can use `%~dp0` to get the path to the bat file and from there navigate to the folders.

Comment: Note that the Windows path separator is `\ `rather than `/`!

Comment: To run an application you don't need to set MAVEN_HOME. Only JAVA_HOME makes sense ...

Comment: @khmarbaise you don't get it ! this app is generating maven projects ! it's a app used to generate maven projects

Comment: It does not matter. MAVEN_HOME is not needed. Only the entry in PATH `apache-maven-3.6.3/bin` is enough and of course JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this one : `%cd%` get the current path (it works like `pwd` in linux):

```
set JAVA_HOME=%cd%\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
echo %JAVA_HOME%
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%

SET MAVEN_HOME=%cd%\apache-maven-3.6.3
echo %MAVEN_HOME%
set PATH=%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```

Comment: Note that this is dependent on the location of the caller, not the bat file location.

Comment: yes she already mentionned in the comments that the bat file, her jar, java and maven all of them in the same folder